# PHP timestamp to Java timestamp

Tags: java, php

I need to convert this 1384174174 timestamp from PHP to Java. This is how I echo the date('Y/m/d H:i:s' ,$dn1['timestamp'] in PHP yet I don't know how to do it in Java. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you'd do it like this:

```
Date date = new Date(1384174174);
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("Y/M/d H:m:s");
String dateFormatted = f.format(date);
```

Watch out for the [format pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) where, unlike PHP, `M` is month in year and `m` is minute in hour.

Answer (score 2):

This method will take your Unix style date and create a Java Date.  It returns a readable string.  It should help you get started.

```
private String unixToString(long unixSeconds) {
    Date date = new Date(unixSeconds);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```